# Web 8 Custom Deployer - location for jar file

Tags: content-delivery, web8, deployer-extension

I've created a Custom Deployer for Web 8 and have built a custom .jar file.  I've added it to the cd_storage config file and want to know which folder I should deploy the .jar to:

- C:\SDL\Web\deployer\lib
- C:\SDL\Web\deployer\services\deployer-service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As all of the specific deployer classes (Processor, ComponentDeployer, etc.) remain in the micro-service folder (and still are  old fashioned "com.tridion..."); I would put it in there, but I think that it doesn't mind as some of the classes used by the deployer-service, are located in the lib folder.

Answer (score 4):

You can indeed place it into any subfolder within the  services folder. I recommend creating a new folder called deployer-extensions or similar in order that it makes upgrading easier.

You will need to reinstall the service if you want the new folder to be added to the class path.